# How to properly honor std::setw and std::fill when overriding << operator in C++

Tags: c++, ostream

I have a custom data type representing a string:

```
struct ByteArray {
   uint32_t len;
   uint8_t* ptr;
}
```

and override << operator to output it to screen.

Version 1:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const ByteArray &dt) {
    os << string((const char*)dt.ptr,dt.len);
    return os;
}
```

Version 2:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const ByteArray &dt) {
    os.write((const char *) dt.ptr, dt.len);
    auto fill = os.width() - dt.len;
    fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<char>(os), fill, os.fill());
    return os;
}
```

My code for output is something like

```
ByteArray& value = ...; // a string of length 25
cout << '|' << left << setw(40) << value;
```

When I use version 1, it works well and displays:

```
|gAaNbDxVTyFjjhgGodAKyy9uk
```

But version 2 displays 17 leading blank spaces:

```
|                 gAaNbDxVTyFjjhgGodAKyy9uk
```

I want to use version 2, as it does not create unnecessary string objects. But how do I handle setw and fill properly?

Thanks!

Update:

When I output multiple rows, they are left-aligned, but have a leading 17 space before the actual data. Please see the example below. This output is generated by the version 2 code above. The actual width is 95 when I set the width to 40.

```
|                 gAaNbDxVTyFjjhgGodAKyy9uk                                                      |
|                 wMEzrsX2KKpTaJGE3uGEUibymG                                                     |                                                   
|                 8cRzJOxCG7z qpfkXKgrQs6ubfOTK                                                  |                                               
|                 A5a1lovY,yQoSHaYon5cGgo1l                                                      |                                            
|                 f1mPa2ts2TUCbZ9UVmuDuu2lXLgfYTP                                                |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues in the code.

1. You are supposed to honor the `left` flag when handling `width`. `setw()` is essentially the same as `width()`, which normally left-aligns or right-aligns depending on the `left` flag. See [`operator <<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) for strings:

   > - If `str.size()` is not less than `os.width()`, uses the range
   >     `[str.begin(), str.end())` as-is
   > - Otherwise, if `(os.flags() & ios_base::adjustfield) == ios_base::left`, places `os.width()-str.size()`, copies of the `os.fill()` character after the character sequence
   > - Otherwise, places `os.width()-str.size()` copies of the `os.fill()` character before the character sequence
2. It is common to clear the padding after using it once: `os.width(0);`.
3. [`ostream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) delegates to [`operator <<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for `char` types. That operator in turn will attempt the padding, which will result in a mess.

   Use [`ostreambuf_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostreambuf_iterator) instead.

Something like this

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const ByteArray& dt) {
    size_t fill = os.width() > dt.len ? os.width() - dt.len : 0;
    if ((os.flags() & ios_base::adjustfield) == ios_base::left) {
        os.write((const char*)dt.ptr, dt.len);
        fill_n(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(os), fill, os.fill());
    }
    else {
        fill_n(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(os), fill, os.fill());
        os.write((const char*)dt.ptr, dt.len);
    }
    os.width(0);
    return os;
}
```

Bonus note: when testing padding, it is prudent to print something before *and* after it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't agree that the problem is caused by the left flag. I only need left align, so I ignore the left flag in my version 2 code. The problem is: now the rows are left-aligned, but they all have a leading 17 space. Please see my update for example. I don't understand where space comes from.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the question. See my updates...

Comment: That is indeed the case. Thanks!